# Что происходит при инициализации функций до начала выполнения кода?

Tags: php

Функции не обязаны быть определены до их использования. Интерпретатор просто ассоциирует определённый участок кода с именем функции или происходит какой то более сложный анализ?

Comment: Например какой?

Comment: Функции обязаны быть определены до их использования.

Comment: @Daniil проверили?

Comment: @teran выполнение PHP кода идёт сверху вниз. Если вызвать функцию до её объявления, php о ней ещё не будет знать

Comment: @Daniil дак вы [проверили](http://ideone.com/oBXKmL)?

Comment: @teran о да, я вам с точностью скажу, что будет PHP Fatal error

Comment: @Daniil Не не будет. Функции не обязаны быть определены до их использования, исключая тот случай, когда функции определяются условно.

Comment: @sanmai Не знаю поэтому и спрашиваю. Может быть какой то синтаксический разбор или ещё что то.

Comment: В интерпритаторе есть своя таблица функций и он проверяет по ним. Вот тут есть реализация функции [function_exists](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1fe57c950519a0520dcf7b5ea7875b27d6934b73/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c)

Comment: Да, действительно, если делать то что вы пишите вне try catch - работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнение php скрипта подразделяется на несколько этапов:

1. Чтение php скрипта. На этом этапе происходит полное чтение всего php скрипта, синтаксический анализ, строится абстрактное синтаксическое дерево.

   Все объявленные в скрипте функции импортируются в глобальную область видимости.
2. Трансляция написанного php кода во внутреннее представление, иначе байт-код.
3. Выполнение php скрипта. На этом этапе происходит построчное выполнение кода. Например, если в первой строке кода содержится вызов функции, которая была определена только в конце файла - функция благополучно выполнится, т.к. php на первом этапе прочитал скрипт целиком, и уже знает вызываемую функцию.

Если рассматривать такой пример:

*Содержимое index.php*

```
<?php
test();
require_once 'lib.php';
?>
```

*Содержимое lib.php*

```
<?php
function test() {

}
?>
```

То в этом случае произойдет ошибка: функция `test()` ещё не была определена, т.к. этап синтаксического анализа не включает в себя выполнение строки кода с
`require_once` (синтаксический анализ вообще не включает в себя выполнение какого-либо кода, а только проверку его на корректность), а значит, php на момент вызова функции `test()` ещё не знает о ней, так как подключение php файла с объявлением этой функции идёт строкой ниже - т.е. php ещё не подключал этот скрипт.

**Следовательно**:
Функции не обязаны быть определены до их использования, если они определены в том же скрипте, в котором вызываются, а иначе php скрипт, в котором определена данная функция, должен быть подключен ПЕРЕД её использованием.

То же правило распространяется и на классы, интерфейсы, трейты.

К слову, если функция объявляется несколько раз, то произойдёт ошибка "такая функция уже объявлена". Например, если подключить php скрипт с функциями с помощью `include`, а затем сделать это ещё раз, то при попытке импортировать функции из подключаемого скрипта - php выдаст фатальную ошибку, что такая-то функция была объявлена. Поэтому скрипты с библиотеками следует подключать с помощью `include_once` или `require_once`.