# Можете объяснить, как работает этот код?

Tags: php

Можете объяснить, как работает этот PHP код?

```
if( true ){
    qwe::$e = 3;
}
class qwe {
    static public $e = 2;
    static function asd(){
        echo qwe::$e;
    }
}

print_r(qwe::$e);
qwe::asd();
```

Результат: 33.

Разве можно обращаться к класу перед объявлением? И почему не переопределилась переменная в классе?

Comment: Что именно непонятно?

Comment: Разве можна обращатса к класу перед обявлением?
І почему не переопределилась переменная в класе

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682524/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 1):

Статичному свойству $e присваивается значение 3, потом два раза это значение выводится на экран.

Comment: Сей ответ не отвечает на вопрос из комментария

Answer (score 1):

Так как класс является статическим и/или в нём присутствуют статические переменные - то можно.

Если у Вас обычный класс без каких-либо статических данных, к которым можно получить доступ через `::` - то тогда нужно создавать новый экземпляр класса и через магические методы уже "стучать".
Вот небольшой пример:

```
class A {
    protected $foo = 'bar';

    public function __get($name){
        return $this->{$name};
    }
}

class B {
    static $foo = 'bar';
}

var_dump((new A())->__get('foo') == B::$foo); // Даст True
```

Только для доступа в новом экземпляре надо будет переопределить магический метод и сделать проверку на то, существует ли переменная.